# Open URL failure in Safari

Tags: iphone

I created my application. I need to open URL in iPhone, safari view directly.

My code as follows:

```
        NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/music/id186152317?i=186153149&uo=4"];
         email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:email];
         if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
         NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
         [super viewDidLoad];
```

But my problem is, the Safari view is opened. But the URL is not opened. It is showing error. The error is

> Cannot Open Page safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

But the URL is opened in browser.

Does anyone know the solution, to open this URL in Safari in iPhone using Objective C?

Comment: better you try with the NSURLconnection from apple document.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you should not be URL encoding the entire URL.  You should only be encoding the keys and the values of each pair in the query string.  In other words, URL encode: `i`, `186153149`, `uo`, and `4`.  Nothing else.  (And technically, you don't even need to encode those because they're all in the ASCII set of alphanumeric characters, which don't need to be encoded)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/ to get exact link.Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding to "`NSUTF8StringEncoding`"

Answer (score 0):

Also check out that after encoding is done then your link

http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/music/id186152317?i=186153149&**uo=4**

changes to

http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/music/id186152317?i=186153149&**ign-mpt=uo%3D4**

hAPPy iCODING...

Answer (score 0):

Strange because Safari on the Mac doesn't complain...

But if you replace your url by `http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/music/id186152317` it seems to work on the iPhone too.