# Open Itunes app link in uiwebView

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, itunes

I want to simply open some apps pages from itunes web site, but when tested in the simulator it shows me ann error that the url is invalid, despite it opens correctly from the mac browser.

My problem is similar to this one and i have write more or less the same code : 
[Open URL Problem in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561067/open-url-problem-in-safari)

Is it impossible to open itues site from safari? links like this I mean :

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id454060218?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apples own [LinkMaker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/)

I also think it's possible to remove the country part of the URL, i.e. remove the `/us/` part so `http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id454060218` would be `http://itunes.apple.com/app/id454060218`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still not working, even when I try to open the link in the Simulator browser, without using any xcode project. Really don't understand that "Apple" don't allow to open "Itunes" from "Safari" !

Comment: I don't think the Simulator even has App Store installed. Otherwise you can have a look here http://memention.com/blog/2009/09/03/Open-Reviews.html for a method I found a while back to open App Store for reviews, don't know if it still works though

Comment: That's it epatel, thanks a lot, I found in others threads that the simulator, since it hasn't itunes, can't open those links. Rather always test in real device..